# PHP Error: Trying to get property of non-object ... on blank line

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I've looked at answers to a few similar questions, but havn't been able to apply to my issue.

I'm getting the error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/h2/548/534548/public_html/index.php on line 22
0 results
```

...from the following code which i've borrowed heavily from the w3schools site:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Nationometer</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "jonnationometer";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT ID, Site_Name, Weather_Forecast, Forecast_Date, Forecast_Time, Further_Information_about_This_Site FROM SiteList";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br>" .$row["ID"]. $row["Site_Name"]. $row["Weather_Forecast"]. $row["Forecast_Date"]. $row["Forecast_Time"]. $row["Further_Information_about_This_Site"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Line 22 highlighted by the error statement is blank (or does it ignore blank lines when counting in the script?)

Greatly appreciate if anyone can offer some guidance regarding how I need to tweak the script to get it to return data.

Comment: What does `$result` contain after your query?

Comment: add `mysqli_error($conn)` see what that throws

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm not sure, how do I check?

Comment: Hi. OK, so I managed to resolve this issue by swapping the code out for another approach which builds a html table and then places the returned data within it. I never really got to the bottom of the meaning of the original error message. What's the best way for me to close this question off?